# c#: generate all json combination from placeholders

Tags: c#, json, combinatorics

I have a file prototypes.csv with the content:

```
PrototypeId;PrototypeBody
1,{header:"test", type:"__type__", dev:"__dev__"}
2,{header:"test", type:"__type__", dev:"4454"}
```

and I have the file type.csv with the content:

```
PrototypeId;Value
1;das
1;cfg
1;lko
2;cfg
2;lko
```

and the file dev.csv with the content:

```
PrototypeId;Value
1;swe
1;cdx
```

I need to generate all possible `jsons` using all values from the placeholders files (type.csv and dev.csv).

Using this input, the result would be:

```
{header:"test", type:"das", dev:"swe"}
{header:"test", type:"cfg", dev:"swe"}
{header:"test", type:"lko", dev:"swe"}
{header:"test", type:"das", dev:"cdx"}
{header:"test", type:"cfg", dev:"cdx"}
{header:"test", type:"lko", dev:"cdx"}
{header:"test", type:"cfg", dev:"4454"}
{header:"test", type:"lko", dev:"4454"}
```

How to generate all combination in an optimal way, if the numbers of placeholders are random (can be from one to 15-20).

I was thinking to read all the placeholders from a prototype line and search a file with the same name as the placeholders and make all possible combinations (in this way I can add various `json` prototype structures without recompiling the application). How to achieve this? Maybe I should create an `expression` with `for` in `for`... based on the number of placeholders, compile it and execute it?

I haven't coded anything related to algorithm because I have no idea how to start.

Comment: What about parsing them to separate objects and using LINQ to join them?

Comment: the number of placeholders in the json prototype is dynamic, it can be 2,3 or 20... and for each placeholder I can have 1,2,3 or 30 values... and this can happen for each placeholder... and it seems a little bit complicated to achieve this with linq...

Comment: In the results list, it appears that you are combining values in type.csv with all the values from the dev.csv file. But, only the 4454 value in the prototypes.csv file is combined with the values in the type.csv file. I don't see any results with __dev__. Does that mean that if dev.csv contains a prototype id for a value in the prototypes.csv file, then the results should not include the value from the prototypes.csv, but should instead be combined with the matching prototype ids in dev.csv?

Comment: @BobBryan if the value of teh json in the file prototypes.csv is something like __ aaa __ then the program should search for the possible values, if not, then this is the fixed value of the json